# C# - Google Chrome crashes when running selenium tests on docker windows

Tags: c#, docker, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, remotewebdriver

I am getting the following error when running selenium c# tests on docker windows. Could anyone please help me on this. I am really struggling to get it solved.

The error that I am getting is shown below:

> OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException : unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed.
> (chrome not reachable)
> (The process started from chrome location C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
> TearDown : System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>
> at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response errorResponse)
> at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
> at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.StartSession(ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)
> at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver…ctor(ICommandExecutor commandExecutor, ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)
> at OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver…ctor(ChromeDriverService service, ChromeOptions options, TimeSpan commandTimeout)
> at SeleniumCore.Core.Chrome.Initialize() in C:\src\SeleniumCore\Core\Chrome.cs:line 58

The code which initializes the chrome is shown below:

```
public class Chrome : IBrowser
{
    public RemoteWebDriver MainDriver { get; private set; }

    private readonly bool Headless;

    public Chrome(AppConfigContext context)
    {
        Headless = context.Headless;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Initialize Chrome Browser Instance.
    /// </summary>
    public void Initialize()
    {
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();

        if (Headless)            
            options.AddArgument("headless");
            options.AddArgument("--disable-gpu");
            options.AddArgument("--no-sandbox");
            options.AddArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage");

        var downloadPath = Controls.DataFilePath + @"Downloads";

        Controls.CreateDirectory(downloadPath);

        options.AddUserProfilePreference("download.default_directory", downloadPath);
        options.AddUserProfilePreference("download.prompt_for_download", false);
        options.AddUserProfilePreference("disable-popup-blocking", "true");



        RemoteWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(@"C:\Chromedrivers\new",options);
        MainDriver = driver;
```

The docker info which I am using :

Client:

Context: default

Debug Mode: false

Plugins:

buildx: Docker Buildx (Docker Inc., v0.7.1)

compose: Docker Compose (Docker Inc., v2.2.1)

scan: Docker Scan (Docker Inc., v0.14.0)

Server:

Containers: 5

Running: 0

Paused: 0

Stopped: 5

Images: 50

Server Version: 20.10.11

Storage Driver: windowsfilter

Windows:

Logging Driver: json-file

Plugins:

Volume: local

Kernel Version: 10.0 19042 (19041.1.amd64fre.vb_release.191206-1406)

Operating System: Windows 10 Pro Version 2009 (OS Build 19042.1466)

OSType: windows

Architecture: x86_64

CPUs: 4

Total Memory: 7.886GiB

Name:

Labels:

Experimental: false

Insecure Registries:

127.0.0.0/8

Live Restore Enabled: false

Product License: Community Engine

Please reply for this. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If your usecase is to connect to the *`RemoteWebDriver`*, instead of:

```
RemoteWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(@"C:\Chromedrivers\new",options);
```

You have to:

```
var MainDriver = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"), DesiredCapabilities.Chrome()); // replace this url with the url of your remote hub
```

Comment: Thank you!! I will have a try like that.